# Show that there exists $\alpha$ such that $f(x) = \alpha x^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Problem:**

> Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ . Suppose that 
>   $$f(x+y) + f(x-y) = 2[f(x)+f(y)]$$
>   for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists $\alpha$ such that $f(x) = \alpha x^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt:**
Frankly, I'm not really sure where to begin. I can rewrite the problem as 
$$\frac{f(x+y) + f(x-y)}{f(x)+f(y)} = 2$$ 
which looks a little bit like the Lipschitz condition. Also, it seems like a clever substitution is going to happend with $f(x-y)$ and $f(x+y)$. Beyond that I can't really get a hold on the problem. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: @Itay4 The other question is about functions on $\mathbb{Q}$, and the highest upvoted answer uses that heavily. The questions are related, of course, but I would not consider this one as a direct duplicate.

Comment: Where is the mistake in the following?

$$f'(x) = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{f(x+y) + f(x-y) - 2f(x)}{2y} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{2f(x) + 2f(y) - 2f(x)}{2y} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{f(y)}{y} $$

Comment: Begin by consider odd cases.  f (0)=f (0+0)=f (0-0)=f (x-x).  So what must f (0) be, what must f (2x)=f (x-x) be?  By induction what must f (nx) be?  f ($\frac nm $x) be.  As f is continuous what ....

Comment: @Ivan Note that $$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-y)}{y}$$ Your expression is equivalent to the difference of these divided by 2, which is zero.

Comment: Oh, that's silly of me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2f(x)+2f(h)-f(x)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2f(h)}{h^2}.$$ Note that if this limit exists, it is equal to $f''(x)$, which is thus constant.

Notice that if we take $y=0$, we obtain $2f(x)=2f(x)+2f(0)$, so $f(0)=0$. Further, consider $x=y=h/2$, and so we obtain $f(h)+f(0)=4f(h/2)$, and thus $$\frac{f(h)}{h^2}=\frac{4f(h/2)}{h^2}=\frac{f(h/2)}{(h/2)^2}.$$ By the continuity of $f$, we have $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(2^{-n})}{2^{-2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(1)}{1}=f(1).$$ Thus, $f$ is second differentiable, and $f''(x)=2f(1)$ for all $x$. It follows that $f(x)=f(1)x^2+cx$ for some constant $c$. Note that $$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(1)(x^2+y^2)+2cx$$ and $$2(f(x)+f(y))=2f(1)(x^2+y^2)+2cx+2cy.$$ Since the two above equations must be equal, we have $2cy=0$ for all $y$, and thus $c=0$.

Thanks to @Ivan for the difference quotient idea.

Comment: Edited my deleted answer with an answer assuming continuity.

Answer (score 5):

It's not true,  unless you impose an additional requirement such as continuity or measurability.  Suppose $g$ is a nonlinear solution to the [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) (i.e. $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$) but it is not of the form $g(x) = cx$).  Then
 $f(x) = g(x^2)$ satisfies your equation but is not of the required form.

Comment: Oh yes thank you. Actually I'm interested in continuous functions. I'll edit the question.